# Perform operations (code) on each item of an array we are imploding without traversing the array twice?

Tags: php, arrays, traversal, implode

Is there a way to perform operations on each items of an array we are imploding without traversing the array twice?

I've run into lambda-based solutions but it traverses the array twice (unless I'm wrong):

```php
$array = array('some','boring','items');
$func = function($arr){
    $return = array();
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $return[] = ucfirst($item);
    }
    return $return;
};
echo ' ' . implode('#', $func($array));
```

A pretty old [report exists on PHP bugtracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40097) but no practical solution were given.

I would like to avoid recoding implode like such:

```php
$iter = new ArrayIterator($array);
while ($iter->valid()) {
    echo ucfirst($iter->current());
    $iter->next();
    if ($iter->valid()) {
        echo '#';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why not. Just use function call in-place, like:

```
$array = array('some','boring','items');

$result = substr(array_reduce($array, function(&$cur, $x)
{
   return $cur.='#'.ucfirst($x);
}, ''), 1);
```

Alternatively (if you want to avoid even string overhead when doing `substr()`) - use

```
$result = ucfirst(array_shift($array)).array_reduce($array, function(&$cur, $x)
{
   return $cur.='#'.ucfirst($x);
}, '');
```

-less "beautiful" - but certainly will use each element only once.

Comment: Thanks, is both working fine and compatible with any "operation" to perform is item.